# Email all cron stdout+stderr output only on stderr

Tags: cron, rocky-linux

I would like cron to only email on stderr output but when it does it should include all stdout and stderr

This is different than the usual question of only emailing on stderr (ie. redirect stdout to /dev/null). In that case, cron only emails the stderr but I would like to see everything for context.

I'm running Rocky 9 with cronie as the cron daemon.

Comment: home and enduser question are offtopic on serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com instead. What is the business related question or issue in here, [what do you really want to solve](https://faq-database.de/doku.php?id=en:x-and-y-problem) because most users forget that point due the have not read [ask] yet

Comment: Fwiw this is a business server related situation... I don't care. If someone wants to move it to superuser go ahead.

Comment: Redirect STDERR and STDOUT each into separate files. If there is anything in STDERR - concatenate and mail both.  If you want to keep the order of messages then you'll probably need to mix some `tee` in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write a script that could approximate a solution to the question of only emailing on stderr output.

The key is storing stdout/stderr to files until stderr is detected and then outputting the combined file.

The combined file can loosely be said to retain stdout/stderr order in so far as tail can iterate over its files quickly enough. If there's no buffering and a command takes more than a second or two and there's some delay between stdout/stderr ouputs then this approach can approximate ordered stdout/stderr output.

I call this script cron-wrapper.sh. It's purpose is to accept a command and arguments and run them.

It's intended to be called from a crontab like this:

30 * * * * root sh cron-wrapper.sh sh cron-job.sh >/dev/null

Note that when outputing everything on stderr "everything" is output to stderr not stdout to fulfill my requirement that cron email everything on stderr output

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Input
cmd=$1
shift

# Run given command in background so we can tail output files immediately
stdoutFile=`mktemp`
stderrFile=`mktemp`
$cmd "${@}" >"$stdoutFile" 2>"$stderrFile" &
cmdPid=$!

# Tail stdout and stderr files
teeFile=`mktemp`
tail -F -s 0.01 --pid=$cmdPid --quiet --silent "$stdoutFile" "$stderrFile" | tee "$teeFile"

# Output everything if stderr output detected
if [ -s "$stderrFile" ]; then
        cat "$teeFile" >&2
fi
    
# Clean up
rm -f "$stdoutFile" "$stderrFile" "$teeFile"
```

Comment: I'm letting this implementation settle with a real cron job to make sure it's doing what I want. Then I'll probably mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the command exits with a non-zero status code, you could try:

```
bash -c 'command 2>&1 > /tmp/err || mail -A /tmp/err user@example.com'
```

where:

- `bash -c ''` enables using multiple commands on a cronjob; you could use a script, too.
- `command` is path to the command to be excuted
- `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout
- `> /tmp/err` saves stdout (now both streams) to a file (path `/tmp/err`)
- `||` runs the second command only if the first failed with a non-zero status code
- `mail -A /tmp/err` sends the file as an attachment

  - `mail user@example.com < /tmp/err` would send it as the message body

You could enhance this using, e.g. `mktemp` to use different path for every log in case of simultaneous runs & `sleep` there is something missing from the end of the file.

Comment: Thank you, this is a helpful comment but does not address the question exactly

Comment: It gives plenty of Legos you can use to build a solution that best fits your needs. You'd likely need a script.